# Passing parameters to powershell script from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am calling a powershell script from a batch file, both in different locations.

I would like to pass the folder location for the powershell script file as well as the parameter, a user entered string in the batch file, from that batch file.

powershell script:

```
$url = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23"
$output="sample.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date
$arg1=$args[0]
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $arg1\$output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

My Batch file :

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\temp\download-rpi.ps1 "\\drives\savehere"
```

Comment: [set /p](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: Why do you need a batch file at all? Just run your script from the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Because he can only call batch from the 3rd party software.

Comment: Perhaps, but that is not stated in the question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart He did not, no, he only mentioned in comments below in answers.

Comment: My point was that the questioner needs to add all relevant details to the question in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have done all of this in a single language instead of using both Powershell and batch, but regardless, here is what you want

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
    set /p "pspath=Enter the path to Powershell: "
    ) else set "pspath=%1"
if "%2"=="" (
    set /p "sharepath=Enter the share parameter: "
    ) else set "sharepath=%2"
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "%pspath% "%sharepath%"
```

How it works:

you can either double click the file which will then prompt for the powershell path and sharepath

OR

run from cmdline and enter the variables after the batch command, which will use `%1` `%2` to set the variables. Examples:

> 1. Double Clicking batch:

```
Enter the path to Powershell: C:\Some Path\
Enter The share parameter: \\some\share
```

***Result***

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Some Path\" "\\some\share"
```

> 2. Running from cmd.exe prompt

```
C:\> BatchFileName.cmd "C:\Some Path\" "\\some\share"
```

***Result***

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Some Path\" "\\some\share"
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to fix my problem

Comment: @Khushi glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, this is done using [parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx):

```
param(
    [string]$Path
)

$url        = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23"
$output     = "sample.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $Path\$output

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

---

An alternative is to use the automatic variable [$MYINVOCATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) to get similar behaviour to an `$args` array but I would not recommend that as you have no way of knowing what unbound parameters will be provided.

```
$url        = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23"
$output     = "sample.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date
$Path       = $MYINVOCATION.UnboundArguments

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $Path\$output

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Comment: @gmsoylman : Thanks. now coming to batch file -   instead of passing hardcoded path(as i passed in batch file for $path) how to pass them as parameters which can be provided at third party ?  Also my batch file is in different folder so i would like to give the path of poweshell script as parameter

Comment: @Khushi Is there a reason you're using a batch file instead of pure PowerShell?

Comment: Yes. I am calling this batch file in a  third part application which does not support calling powerscript file directly.