# how to parameterized powershell scipt from batch

Tags: powershell

I am using one power shell script that has one function like below, it three parameters.

```
Function Get-ServiceAlert
{
param(
[String]$ComputerList,[String[]]$includeService,[String]$Reportname)
........
}
```

At the end of the script,
when I call the function and pass parameters hardcoded or using variable it works fine. like the following

```
$servername='C:\Server\server.txt'
$Reportname='C:\Server\Reoport.html'

Get-ServiceAlert -ComputerList $servername -includeService AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc,AeLookupSvc,AppMgmt -Reportname $Reportname
```

I want to call this function using parameter. so that I can call it using batch file. I am unable to call this using parameter.

Comment: You are you calling it in the batch file? Why not just run it as a powershell command?

Comment: My requirement is to make it parameterized instead of hard code. Even if I run it as power shell, how can I make such a way to provide parameter for the above two values.

Comment: I'm confused. Your example with variables `Get-ServiceAlert -ComputerList $servername -includeService AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc, AeLookupSvc, AppMgmt -Reportname $Reportname` can already take in parameters. You simply need to switch the value your variable is assigned. If you can give me examples of different inputs and the command that might help me answer your question.

Comment: For example, I have created a bat file, with the following code,                  set servername=C:\Server\Server.txt
set Reportname=C:\Server\Reoport.html


powershell.exe  C:\Server\ServiceMonitorT.ps1  -ComputerList %servername% -Reportname %Reportname%                                                                                                                                                                                                                This is not working.

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461599/passing-parameters-to-powershell-script-from-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Shadowzee points out, PS can do this directly, there is no need for a batch file. Passing a set of parameters means, making PS .ps1 take paramerters.

You can call a PS function form a batch file, you call them in a PS session.

If you are saying, you want to run a .ps1 and send params to it, then do that direclty, meaning, like this...

Save the below as Get-ServiceAlert.ps1 not a function in a .ps1.
This allows you to pass the parameters when you use the script.

```
Param
(
    [String]$ComputerList,
    [String[]]$includeService,
    [String]$Reportname     
)
```

The run the script from the consolehost like this...

```
D:\Scripts\Get-ServiceAlert.ps1 -ComputerList $_ -includeService 'Service(s) to include' -Reportname 'D:\Scripts\Reports\ServiceReport.txt'
```

Your question indicates that you might not be all into PS yet, as what you are trying is not how functions work externally.

You use function inside the script not externally, unless you turn your script into a module (.psm1) that you can load (Import-Module), thus exposing the functions in the module externally.

Take a few and view some of the freely avaialbe PS video training  on Microsoft Virtual Academy, MS Channel9, and Youtube.

Comment: `D:\Scripts\Get-ServiceAlert.ps1 -ComputerList $_` This bit might not be helpful.

Comment: I want to call this .ps1 script from Jenkins, where I want to pass two parameter one for servername and one for reportname . This script contain only one function that is Get-ServiceAlert , and the following line. Get-ServiceAlert -ComputerList $servername -includeService AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc,AeLookupSvc,AppMgmt -Reportname $Reportname            . It has to be a function because it will loop through all the task for all the servers that are mentioned in the servername file.

Comment: If I write param([String]$servername,[String]$Reportname)




Function global:Get-ServiceAlert
{
param(
[String]$ComputerList,[String[]]$includeService,[String]$Reportname)........}

Comment: and then   Get-ServiceAlert -ComputerList $servername -includeService AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc,AeLookupSvc,AppMgmt -Reportname $Reportname   . then nothing happens. it seems function is not getting called for those two parameters.